# Continuity Question in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, continuity

Prove that if

$$f: A \to \mathbb R$$ is continuous at $a$ and $f(a) > 0$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta )\cap  A \implies f(x) > 0$$

Literally have no idea how to start this question

Comment: I attempted to fix your post, let me know if it is not correct.

Comment: It Is correct, Thank you!

Comment: **Hint:** Use the definition of continuity at $a$ with $\varepsilon=\dfrac{f(a)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for any $\delta>0$, there exists $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ such that $f(x)\leq 0$.

Define $\delta_n=\frac1n$. According to our assumption, there exists $x_n\in(a-\delta_n,a+\delta_n)$ such that $f(x_n)\leq 0$. Then we can construct sequence $\{\delta_n\}$ and sequence $\{x_n\}$.

Clearly, $\delta_n$ converges to 0 as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then we have $x_n$ converges to a.

By the continuity of $f$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=f(a)>0$. Contradiction.

Comment: Do not know limits yet, only know about continuity

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(0,\infty)$ is open, and $a \in f^{-1} (0,\infty)$ which is open since $f$ is continuous. Hence there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(a,\epsilon) \subset f^{-1} (0,\infty)$.

**Addendum**: Some definitions/clarifications:

1) A function $f$ is continuous at $a$ **iff** for any open set $V$ containing $f(a)$,
there exists an open set $U$ containing $a$ such that $f(U) \subset V$.

2) A subset $U \subset A$ is open **iff** for any $x \in U$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\cap A \subset U$.

Using 1), we have $V=(0,\infty)$ is open and $f(a) \in V$, hence there exists
an open $U$ containing $a$ such that $f(x) \in V$ for all $x \in U$.

Since $U$ is open, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $(a-\delta, a+ \delta) \cap A\subset U$.

If $x \in (a-\delta, a+ \delta) \cap A\subset U$, then $f(x) \in V$, or equivalently $f(x) >0$.

Comment: no idea how this helps

Comment: Well, it is a complete answer. I have added the relevant definitions.